# JavaScript Find In Text File

Tags: javascript

I have been searching for a JavaScript "Find In Page" tool to place in a HTML file so that when I enter a search term and click submit, the script will search a TEXT file of my choice and find a match on the text page for the entry submitted. Can someone give me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FileSearch.aspx might help!! - Havent used it. Just googled.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex pattern matching to highlight the searched text

Check this
http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm

Comment: Thanks all! But, I'm not sure these suggestions will work. This is an example of what I'm looking for: Page A - This is the start page: 

http://www.mobilestimulus.com/tests/field_search/index

Employee enters part# on page A, and Part# is highlighted on page B. Am I right in thinking the two ideas given here will not work for this?

Page B, the page to be searched, is a .txt file. Example:

http://www.mobilestimulus.com/tests/field_search/file1

Comment: So, you can going to search a .txt file which is page B, from Page A